# VueJS display dynamic modal component

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, vuex

I have posts and replys s.t. replies belong to posts via the attribute reply.posts_id.

I am attempting to show the reply form as a modal for the user to enter a reply. However, I want to create a generic Modal component that I can use everywhere with content that is specified in another component built for a specific context.

Reply to post is the first place I woul like this to work.

Currently, the Vuex correctly returns Modal visible:true when the reply button is clicked, but the modal does not render and I get the error message showing that the Modal component is not found:

```
Unknown custom element: <ModalReplyForm> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I am using vuex to manage the visibility of the modal. Here are the relevant files:

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'
...

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    status: '',
    ...
    modalVisible: false,
    modalComponent: null
  },
  mutations: {
    ...
    showModal(state, componentName) {
      console.log('showing the modal')
      state.modalVisible = true;
      state.modalComponent = componentName;
    },
    hideModal(state) {
      console.log('hiding the modal')
      state.modalVisible = false;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    ...
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated: state => !!state.user,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
    user: state => state.user,
    token: state => state.token,
    posts: state => {
      return state.posts;
    }
...
  }
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-modal></app-modal>
    <NavigationBar />
    <div class="container mt-20">
      <router-view />
    </div>
    <vue-snotify></vue-snotify>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AppModal from '@/components/global/AppModal';
import NavigationBar from '@/components/layout/NavigationBar'
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    AppModal,
    NavigationBar
  }
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.is-danger {
  color: #9f3a38;
}
</style>
```

Post.vue (houses the button to call the reply modal):

```
<template>
  <div class="row ui dividing header news">
    <!-- Label -->
    <div class="m-1 col-md-2 ui image justify-content-center align-self-center">
      <img v-if="post.avatar_url" :src="post.avatar_url" class="mini rounded"/>
      <v-gravatar v-else :email="post.email" class="mini thumbnail rounded image rounded-circle z-depth-1-half"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Excerpt -->
    <div class="col-md-9 excerpt">

...

        <!-- Feed footer -->
      <div class="feed-footer row">
        <div class="small"> {{ post.created_at | timeAgo }}</div>
        <button type="button" flat color="green" @click="showModal('ModalReplyForm')">
          <i class="fa fa-reply" ></i>

...

        <div v-show="postOwner(post)" class="">
          <button type="button" flat color="grey" @click="deletePost(post.id)">
            <i class="fa fa-trash " ></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import PostsService from '../../services/PostsService'
import RepliesService from '../../services/RepliesService'
import Replies from '@/components/Reply/Replies'
import ReplyForm from '@/components/Reply/ReplyForm'
export default {
  name: "Post",
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    Replies,
    ReplyForm
  },
  computed: {
    me() {
      return this.$store.getters.user
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['showModal']),
    ...
  }
};
</script>
```

AppModal.vue - generic Modal component

```
<template>
  <div class="c-appModal">
    <div class="c-appModal__overlay" v-if="visible"></div>
    <div class="c-appModal__content" v-if="visible" @click.self="hideModal"></div>
      <div class="c-appModal__innerContent">
        <component :is="component"></component>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'AppModal',
  data() {
    return {
      component: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      visible: 'modalVisible',
      modalComponent: 'modalComponent'
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['hideModal'])
  },
  watch: {
    modalComponent(componentName) {
      if (!componentName) return;

      Vue.component(componentName, () => import(`@/components/modals/${componentName}`));

      this.component = componentName;
    }
  },
  created() {
    const escapeHandler = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape' && this.visible) {
        this.hideModal();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', escapeHandler);
    this.$once('hook:destroyed', () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', escapeHandler);
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

ModalReplyForm - specific reply modal content

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="c-modalReply">
      <div>
        <label for="reply">Your comment</label>
        <div class="field">
          <textarea name="reply" v-model="reply" rows="2" placeholder="Compose reply"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button class="c-modalReply__cancel" @click="hideModal">Cancel</button>
      <button class="c-modalReply__post" :disabled="!isFormValid" @click="createReply">Reply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RepliesService from '@/services/RepliesService'
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: "ModalReplyForm",
  // props: {
  //   post: {
  //     type: Object,
  //     required: true
  //   }
  // },
  data() {
    return {
      reply: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isFormValid() {
      return !!this.reply;
    },
    currentGroup() {
      return this.$store.getters.currentPost;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations([
      'hideModal'
    ]),
    async createReply () {
      let result = await RepliesService.addReply({
        reply: {
          body: this.reply,
          postId: this.post.id
        }
      });
      this.$emit("reply-created");
      this.hideModal();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

This message says that you never imported/defined ModalReplyForm, which you have not.

In my own generic modal, I ended up having to import all the components that might appear within the modal itself.

If you add a:

```
import ModalReportForm from ...
```

and a:

```
components: {
  ModalReplyForm
}
```

to AppModal.vue, the modal should then do what you expect.

Comment: following this tutorial: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/building-a-modal-dialog-with-vue-and-vuex/, they do not specifically register each component, so that is what I was trying.  Your approach looks like it will work, though I think my css is off at the moment

Comment: I missed the dynamic import line in your one component.  That setup SHOULD work.  Check that componentName is getting set correctly.

That is probably why the error was popping up.  Your dynamic import is not working as expected?